# How do I revert/reset pushed Commits?

Tags: git, visual-studio, cmd, gitlab

I did not write down what I have done, so I can´t explain it exactly.

I had an "working" commit on the Server and pulled it. Now I played around and changed something stupid in a File, commited it "update1" and pushed it.
Made a reset on my local Repo to "working", which also updated the main branch on the Remote to "working". However, now I have the problem that everything afterwards "update1" is in the "incoming" tab.

When I now want to push something new to the Server I first have to pull everything after "working", although the remote head is on "working" and I don´t want to see anything after that anymore.

I have tried to fix this now so often that I have a tree with six splits in it and seemingly the wrong commit order. Ohh and sometimes between those steps the Remote does not show where the head is.

-> What do I have to do in order to get rid of everything after my "working" commit?
I would prefer the answer in Visual Studio, but I don´t care that much as long as it works.

**EDIT, summarized:**
1.) I now have a dozen commits after my "working" commit. -> I want back to "working". The main is at the newest commit "update12".

2.) I click on "working" and do reset --hard. Now in VS the local history only shows all commits up to "working". BUT, everything after it is now in the Tab "incoming". The main is at "working" and on the remote too, but on the remote it still shows all the commits after "working".

3.) Git demands that I pull everything before I do a push. I do not understand why if the remote head should be on the "working" commit.

4.) What do I have to do to not get all those faulty updates anymore?

Comment: To get back to the working commit run `git reset --hard <commit sha>` and you can push that to the remote with `git push --force` (be very careful with force pushing unless you know that it is exactly what you want)

Comment: I strongly recommend to prefer `--force-with-lease` to `--force`

Comment: Yeah… no offense but it sounds like you’re not totally sure what’s going on. we won’t be able to help diagnose without much more specific information, but I’d be very careful about force pushing until you have a better handle on the situation. Force pushing erases part of the git history and makes the repository unable to recover what you erase.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado ...maybe that´s why I am asking here?....

Comment: @joshmeranda, the problem is that I did do that, no? I did reset --hard in VS to the "working" commit, and the head of the Remote does change automatically, but then it wants to pull me all changes after "working" since those commits are still in the Remote. Although, the head of Remote is on "working".

Comment: You are using visual-studio (vscode? vscodium? specify exact version) which may be interfering with "normal" Git usage, but remember the difference between reset and revert: reset, at least the way you're using it, means "go back in time" (and lose subsequent commits), and revert means "add new commits while keeping the old commits; use the revert to undo the effect of some previous commit(s)". Git is greedy for new commits, so revert is much easier to get right. Resetting commits away works fine—but now Git thinks the commits you removed are "new" and is eager to put them back!

Comment: Your GitLab clone *has* the commits you're trying to remove. So Git will see them as "new" and want you to merge / pull / otherwise incorporate them again. You must convince the GitLab clone to drop the commits as well, and this requires a `--force`-style push, such as `--force-with-lease` or `--force`. Remember, too, that if this is a *public* repository, there may be even more clones, all of which could *also* have the commits you want removed. All of *those* Gits will be eager to put those commits back in.

Comment: You can sometimes think of a removed (reset-away) commit like some kind of persistent, highly infectious virus. (Not like anyone has any experience with viruses these days, right?) It's *really hard* to get rid of it, you have to cure *everyone simultaneously*. Once you've done that, it's gone, but if even one person (or one Git repository) has the virus, it comes right back.

Comment: Visual Stuido 19, ...  I tried to do the reset --force and then push, but it complains that I first have to pull everything ... lol

Comment: @SuperNev when you `git reset --hard <commit>` you are reverting to the good commit as you know. The important part is that you `git push --force`. This will tell `git` not to run a couple checks including the one you mention. From the man page `This flag disables these checks, and can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care`.